# How to change urls order in Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm getting updates from thousands of web pages. There can be multiple pages with the same domain. I've set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to 1 second so I don't overload servers.

Spider works well but if there are for example 100 urls of the same domain next to each other, it slows crawling because Spider has to wait 1 second after each request.

Is it possible to make it crawl next urls with different domain so Spider doesn't have to wait?

For example:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 3
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
```

URLS: A.com/1 ,A.com/2 ,A.com/3 ,A.com/4 ,B.com/1 ,B.com/2 ,B.com/3

Spider will start scraping first three urls. It will take at least three seconds because of download delay. But it would be faster if it processed B.com/1 instead of A.com/2 (for example).

```
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...

    def __init__(self, scraping_round, frequencies=None):
        super(MainSpider, self).__init__())
        ...

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.err, dont_filter=True)
```

Maybe I should reorder `urls` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definitely yes**, reordering the list of scheduled requests would help. Can be done like this:

```
import random

class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ....

    def start_requests(self):
        random.shuffle(self.urls)
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.err, dont_filter=True)
```

Reordering requests that are created subsequently while crawling is more difficult, unfortunately, but maybe this already helps.

**Another fix:** massively increase CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.

The scrapy documentation suggests to set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS at least to 100 if you want to crawl many domains in parallel:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#increase-concurrency

**The reason for this / detailed explanation**

Based on the source code of `scrapy/core/downloader.py, engine.py, scraper.py and scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py` it seems scrapy fills up its processing queue with up to CONCURRENT_REQUESTS from the scheduler and does checking the domains for observing the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN later down the processing chain.

If the scheduler contains a bunch of requests for the same domain in a row you might have multiple requests for the same domain being pulled into the processing queue and thus effectively blocking processing of other domains. This is especially likely to happen if CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is very low as in your example.

This is a known issue described here: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2474

**Alternative solutions**

A even better solution than increasing CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to a very high value would be using https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera as a crawling frontier ... which is basically doing what you suggested: reordering the scheduled requests for optimal processing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have set concurrent requests to 100 but in the question is 3 as a simple example. But I can have 2000 urls from the same domain next to each other in list so 100 won't help me. I will probably go with randomized enqueuing or grouping urls by domain. Frontera seems to be good but isn't it overkill for this? Or maybe if you will, could you post here an example with frontera and my spider?

Comment: Yes, if you have that many urls from the same domain next to each other it will help alot to randomize them. Calling `random.shuffle` on your list of urls should do the trick ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle ).

Comment: Frontera will help to squeeze out the last bit of parallelism, but chances are that randomizing the list will be sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: Randomizing is the first choice but maybe grouping urls by domain would be the best and quite simple option. I would create a dictionary with domains as keys and lists of urls as values. Then I would create a list by popping one by one from these lists. Pop url from first group, second, third .... and repeat until all groups are empty. It's not an ideal solution probably but it seems to be quite effective.

Comment: Depends. If the groups of same-domain urls are almost of equal size your approach would be a tad better than randomization (provided CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is really high). But if there are many domains with only few urls and few domains with many urls, then randomizing would result in a more balanced schedule.

Answer (score 0):

`DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting **is** applied per website.

> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.

from docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay

So what you want should work by default. When spider starts, it queues every url in `start_urls` immediately and then sorts the delay etc.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand: If urls list is A.com/1, A.com/2, A,com/3, A.com/4, B.com/1, B.com/2 and CONCURENT_REQUESTS = 3 and DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1, it should start with A.com/1 and B.com/1 "paralelly" and then after one second A.com/2 + B.com/2. Is it true? I don't want to wait to crawl B.com until A.com is crawled.

Comment: yes, A.com and B.com will have no shared delay so they would go in pararell together.

Comment: No it wouldn't. A.com/1, A.com/2, A.com/3 would fill up all 3 processing slots as they would be pulled first from the scheduler. See also my answer. This is a known issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2474